# Recursive Spider causing problems in my program

Tags: python, scrapy

Trying to write a web scraping program and it works fine but it is outputting the data in wrong order and someone recommended that it might be due to the fact that my spider is a recursive spider.  So how would I go about changing my spider into a non recursive spider?

```
# Spider class
class MySpider(Spider):
    # Name of Spider
    name = 'splash_spider'
    # getting all the url + ip address + useragent pairs then request them

    def start_requests(self):
        # get the file path of the csv file that contains the pairs from the settings.py
        with open(self.settings["PROXY_CSV_FILE"], mode="r") as csv_file:
            # requests is a list of dictionaries like this -> {url: str, ua: str, ip: str}
            requests = process_csv(csv_file)
            for i, req in enumerate(requests):
                x = len(requests) - i
                # Return needed url with set delay of 3 seconds
                yield SplashRequest(url=req["url"], callback=self.parse, args={"wait": 3},
                    # Pair with user agent specified in csv file
                    headers={"User-Agent": req["ua"]},
                    # Sets splash_url to whatever the current proxy that goes with current URL  is instead of actual splash url
                    splash_url = req["ip"],
                    priority = x,
                    meta={'priority': x}  # <- check here!!
                    )

    # Scraping function that will scrape URLs for specified information
    def parse(self, response):
        #  Initialize item to function GameItem located in items.py, will be called multiple times
        item = GameItem()
        # Initialize saved_name
        saved_name = ""
        # Extract card category from URL using html code from website that identifies the category.  Will be outputted before rest of data
        item["Category"] = response.css("span.titletext::text").get()
        # For loop to loop through HTML code until all necessary data has been scraped
        for game in response.css("tr[class^=deckdbbody]"):
            # Initialize saved_name to the extracted card name
            saved_name  = game.css("a.card_popup::text").get() or saved_name
            # Now call item and set equal to saved_name and strip leading '\n' from output
            item["Card_Name"] = saved_name.strip()
            # Check to see if output is null, in the case that there are two different conditions for one card
            if item["Card_Name"] != None:
                # If not null than store value in saved_name
                saved_name = item["Card_Name"].strip()
            # If null then set null value to previous card name since if there is a null value you should have the same card name twice
            else:
                item["Card_Name"] = saved_name
            # Call item again in order to extract the condition, stock, and price using the corresponding html code from the website
            item["Condition"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_7 a::text").get()
            item["Stock"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_8::text").get()
            item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9::text").get()
            if item["Price"] == None:
                item["Price"] = game.css("td[class^=deckdbbody].search_results_9 span[style*='color:red']::text").get()

            # Return values
            yield item
            # Finds next page button
            priority = response.meta['priority']
            next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(., "- Next>>")]/@href').get()
            # If it exists and there is a next page enter if statement
            if next_page is not None:
                # Go to next page
                yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse, priority=priority, meta={'priority': priority})
```

**UPDATE 1**

So the problem I have several URLs each of which has multiple pages and so the problem is it will scrape all the page 1s and then all the page2s and so on instead of all the pages of the first URL and then all the pages of the second URL and so on.  So I implemented priorities to try and fix it but it did not work. Now instead of doing all the URls though it is just doing 2 at a time.  Scraping page one of URL 1 than page 1 of URL 2 and back and forth until one is done than it goes to get the next URL. I have a sample output below.  I removed some of the lines because there is a lot of data on each page.  And each category is a different URL so you will notice that is goes back and forth.

```
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Crypt of Agadeem", "Condition": "PL", "Stock": "21", "Price": "$2.85"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Crypt Ripper", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "92", "Price": "$0.15"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Day of Judgment", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "Out of Stock", "Price": "$3.49"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Day of Judgment", "Condition": "PL", "Stock": "14", "Price": "$2.85"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Demolish", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "87", "Price": "$0.15"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Desecrated Earth", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "77", "Price": "$0.15"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Impulse", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "34", "Price": "$0.49"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Impulse", "Condition": "PL", "Stock": "17", "Price": "$0.39"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Infantry Veteran", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "65", "Price": "$0.15"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Goblin Ruinblaster", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "54", "Price": "$0.25"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Goblin Shortcutter", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "64", "Price": "$0.15"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Goblin War Paint", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "88", "Price": "$0.15"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Gomazoa", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "59", "Price": "$0.25"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Grappling Hook", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "Out of Stock", "Price": "$0.49"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Graypelt Refuge", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "311", "Price": "$0.25"},
{"Category": "Zendikar", "Card_Name": "Grazing Gladehart", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "159", "Price": "$0.15"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Knight of the Mists", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "56", "Price": "$0.15"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Knight of Valor", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "40", "Price": "$0.15"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Kookus", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "39", "Price": "$0.99"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Kookus", "Condition": "PL", "Stock": "40", "Price": "$0.79"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Kyscu Drake", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "59", "Price": "$0.25"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Lead-Belly Chimera", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "44", "Price": "$0.25"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Lichenthrope", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "36", "Price": "$0.99"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Lichenthrope", "Condition": "PL", "Stock": "40", "Price": "$0.79"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Lightning Cloud", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "39", "Price": "$0.99"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Lightning Cloud", "Condition": "PL", "Stock": "38", "Price": "$0.79"},
{"Category": "Visions", "Card_Name": "Longbow Archer", "Condition": "NM/M", "Stock": "67", "Price": "$0.29"},
```

Comment: Show us some sample output, and explain how it's out of order.

Comment: @JohnGordon Ok I will Update question.

Comment: @JohnGordon I added in some sample output for clarity.